# Svelte-Apollo not sending a request

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, svelte

In my component I am doing this

```js
//register.svelte
    import { gql } from "@apollo/client";
    import { mutation } from "svelte-apollo";
    import { goto } from "@sapper/app";
    import { userStore } from "../stores/userStore";

    const REGISTER = gql`
        mutation register(
            //variables
        ) {
            register(
                registerInput: {
                    //variables
                }
            ) {
                //variables
            }
        }
    `;
    const register = mutation(REGISTER);

    let firstName = "";
    let lastName = "";
    let email = "";
    let password = "";
    let confirmPassword = "";
    let loading = false;
    let response = {};
    let errors = {};

    async function registerUser() {
        try {
            loading = true;
            response = await register({
                variables: {
                    //variables
                },
            });

            const {
                //variables
            } = response.data.register;

            $userStore = {
                //variables
            };
            loading = false;

            // persisting the token line
            goto("/app/dashboard");
        } catch (err) {
            errors = err;
        }
    }
```

In my markup I have a form where I have a `button[type=submit]` nested in it, and the function to register is called on submitting the form.

There is a really similar component, login, that is written the same, and yet Login works fine, and register does not even send a request.

Is there anything I could have missed?

I have a `debug` block checking whether the request object has changed or not, but it does not change at all.

EDIT
Here is my logic for configuring the client

```
import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context";
    // to write gql "import {gql} from '@apollo/client'
    import {
        ApolloClient,
        createHttpLink,
        InMemoryCache,
    } from "@apollo/client";
    import { setClient } from "svelte-apollo";
    import fetch from "cross-fetch";

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
        uri: "validaddresshere",
        fetch,
    });

    const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
        return {
            headers: {
                ...headers,
                Authorization: localStorage.getItem("token")
                    ? `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`
                    : "",
            },
        };
    });

    const client = new ApolloClient({
        link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });
```

EDIT 2
The problem seems to be that I am trying to access a variable that's before initialisation. Which I have initialised. To be more precise, it says I have `firstName` as `undefined`, even though you can clearly see it is initialised with `let firstName = ""`

Answer (score 1):

Couple debugging points you could try, Is registerUser() ever being called? If so, does your try/catch fail? ( I would log the error in the catch to see if it does ), 3rd option is that your await register() keeps waiting.

Try logging in the 1st line of registerUser() function & in your catch to get a little bit more information.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This more of a comment, than an answer.

Comment: @Elan it keeps waiting from what I see. Not sure why. I got to the line just before `await register`

Comment: Then you have your answer, your API is not resolving the request.

And thanks @AbbasAkhundov, I understand it's more of a comment, but I hoped that would lead to him finding his answer, which I think it did.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Elan for suggesting how to find out what the problem was.

I had to change the name of variables to make it work. To be more precise.

In my file I had initialised my form variables as

```js
var firstName = "";
var lastName = "";
var email = "";
var password = "";
var confirmPassword = "";
var loading = false;
var response = {};
var errors = {};
```

in my `register()` function I had

```js
async function registerUser() {
        try {
            loading = true;

            response = await register({
                variables: {
                    firstName,
                    lastName,
                    email,
                    language: "en-US",
                    password,
                    confirmPassword,
                },
            });
```

the error that popped up said that I could not access `firstName` before initialisation even though I did not do that. I don't fully understand what happened.